# не получается подключить docker контейнер к сушествующей базе

Tags: postgresql, docker

всем привет !  нужна помощь в понимании докера

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: p4
    ports:
      - "5436:5432"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: dmitry
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
      POSTGRES_DB: testbase1
#      PGDATA:
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  web:
    image: dmitry123123/web4
    container_name: web4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5006:5000"
    environment:
        POSTGRES_HOST: db
    links:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

если я запускаю его с помощью docker compose up то все в порядке
и запускается два контейнера postgres и web4  но что если я хочу запустить еще один web4 разумеется на другом порту и подключить к существующему контейнеру на порту 5436 , как мне это сделать  я получаю ошибку

could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5436?

или к еще одному запущенному экземпляру postgres на порту 5435

а еще как мне подключить web4 к существующей локальной базе postgres на порту 5432
если это возможно то хотелось бы увидеть строчку запуска, а то у меня какое-то недопонимание

Answer (score 0):

Для осуществления ваших мечт надо чтобы ваши приложения работали в одной подсети и видели друг друга по alias.
Есть сложный путь - после запуска использовать `docker network ls`, пытаться найти созданную подсеть по имени, ну и новому контейнеру указать ее при запуске.

Либо, решаем это на уровне docker-compose.

1. Добавляем в ваш файл секцию `network`

```
networks:
    app_network:
        # Общая сеть для приложений
        name: 'app_network'
```

2. Прописываем ее в сервис `db`

```
     db:
        ...
        networks:
            app_network:
                aliases:
                    - db.local
```

Теперь, если для запуска второго контейнера создать свой compose
и прописать ему аналогично сеть app_network, то база будет доступна по алиасу `db.local`

Comment: Сергей, спасибо , попробую !